# Inverse of Jacobian for coordinate transformations, is there a second-order analog?

Tags: coordinate-systems, jacobian

Consider a coordinate transformation $\mathbf{y}(\mathbf{x})$. To keep things simple let's work in 2 dimensions so that we have a transformation $(x_1,x_2)$ to $(y_1, y_2) = \big(y_1(x_1,x_2), y_2(x_1,x_2)\big)$. Suppose the inverse transformation exists where $(x_1,x_2) = \big(x_1(y_1,y_2),x_2(y_1,y_2)\big)$ (but it might be very complicated).

I believe the following result is true:
$$
\mathbb{J} = \left[ \begin{matrix} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y_1} &  \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y_2} \\ \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial y_1} &  \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial y_2}  \end{matrix}  \right] \ = \ \left[ \begin{matrix} \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} &  \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_2} \\ \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1} &  \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_2}  \end{matrix}  \right]^{-1}
$$
Which allows for a simple way to compute the derivatives $\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial y_{k}}$.

My question is, is there an analogous way to compute the second derivatives $\frac{\partial^2 x_j}{\partial y_{k}\partial y_{\ell}}$?

EDIT: Could it involve a $4\times 4$ matrix of the form
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix} \frac{\partial \mathbb{J}}{\partial y_1} &  \frac{\partial \mathbb{J}}{\partial y_2} \\ \frac{\partial \mathbb{J}}{\partial y_1} &  \frac{\partial \mathbb{J}}{\partial y_2}  \end{matrix}  \right] \ ?
$$